# Android Speech Recognition while music is playing

Tags: android, audio, service, voice-recognition, beep

referencing to Hoans answer here [Jelly Bean Beep In Speech Recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370360/jelly-bean-beep-in-speech-recognition) I tried to implement a speech recognizer in the background.

And it works all fine. The service runs in background and listens to words the user say. 
My problem is:

If a music player is running and the speech recognizer restarts, the system sound stream is muted to prevent the beep sound of speech recognition. But muting this stream paues and mutes the music player, too.

Does anyone have an idea how to prevent the beep sound without muting the whole system?

I already tried to mute another stream but the system stream is the only one muting the beep.

I test on a Nexus 4 with Android 4.4

Best regards.

Comment: Why would you want to have music playing while you're trying to recognize words from a human speaker (effectively adding "noise")? Are you trying to perform speech recognition on the music itself?

Comment: I try to start the next song in the list by just saying next. What I want to have is saying "Player", the recognition plays a sound and pauses the player. Than command like "Next". The player starts next song and recognition goes in defualt mode waiting for "Player"#

Comment: Same problem with concurrent TextToSpeech. Bad to know that this is still happening in KitKat. I am wondering, instead of muting stream it is possible to override the default beep?